# C++ cannot open source file, additional directory listed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, glfw

I am using Visual Studio 2019, and I'm trying to include codes from open source GLFW. Things were working completely fine, but when I tried to make another project based on this method again it's not working.

It shows 'Cannot open include file: 'GLFW/glfw3.h': No such file or directory'

[image: Picture which includes error, additional directory, header file directory in folders]

Comment: Some thoughts, SolutionDir doesn't point to ...\OpenGL, missing back-/slash after SolutionDir. Try slashes instead of backslashes?

Comment: Is the SolutionDir OpenGL?

Comment: Yes it is, here's a picture of it showing the full directory https://imgur.com/wTe1txx

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the steps to add `GLFW` and it worked well. You could check whether there are any missing steps.

1. Create a `Dependencies` folder in your project directory, copy the `include` and `lib-vc2019` folders of `glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN32` to `Dependencies`.
   [image]
2. Set `Configuration` to `All Configurations` and set `Platform` to `Win32`
   [image]
3. Add `$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\GLFW\include` in `Proeperties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories`
   [image]
4. Add `$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\GLFW\lib-vc2019` in `Proeperties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`

[image]

5. Add `glfw3.lib;opengl32.lib;User32.lib;Gdi32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)` in `Proeperties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`

[image]